# toggle switch only on confirmation from the user using angular, typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a toggle switch. when i turn it off and based on a variable, a pop up modal will be displayed asking to confirm the turn off. if user clicks on turn off button , only then the toggle should turn off. if user clicks on cancel button in the modal, then the toggle should not turn off , it should be in on state only. I found solutions for this problem using jQuery. but I don't want to use jQuery. so please give solutions in angular, typescript, bootstrap. I'm new to angular. hence it would be more understandable if you could explain the solution. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the modal working yet? I assume you're using event AND two way binding on the toggel to listed for changs. You should be able to pass data back from the modal - perhaps a boolean, then you can set the toggle's value based what was passed back from the modal.